# Stay on scene in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flv

I am creating a small flash project which has few scenes, in one of them I've exported FLV video(5 minutes). When I test this scene it plays the whole video, but when I run the project it is not showing the whole video(less then one second on this scene and goes to the next one). If I'll increase the length of the timeline to show the whole video then the project won't compile because of too many frames. Is there any way to play the whole exported video and then go to the next scene? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `stop();` and it worked.